# R - how to select elements from sublists of a list by their name

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
list(list("A[1]" = data.frame(W = 1:5),
          "A[2]" = data.frame(X = 6:10),
          B = data.frame(Y = 11:15),
          C = data.frame(Z = 16:20)),
     list("A[1]" = data.frame(W = 21:25),
          "A[2]" = data.frame(X = 26:30),
          B = data.frame(Y = 31:35),
          C = data.frame(Z = 36:40)),
     list("A[1]" = data.frame(W = 41:45),
          "A[2]" = data.frame(X = 46:50),
          B = data.frame(Y = 51:55),
          C = data.frame(Z = 56:60))) -> dflist
```

I need my output to also be a list of list with length 3 so that each sublist retains elements whose names start with `A[` while dropping other elements.

Based on some previous questions, I am trying to use this:

```
dflist %>% 
    map(keep, names(.) %in% "A[")
```

but that gives the following error:

```
Error in probe(.x, .p, ...) : length(.p) == length(.x) is not TRUE
```

Trying to select a single element, for example just `A[1]` like this:

```
dflist %>% 
    map(keep, names(.) %in% "A[1]")
```

also doesn't work. How can I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```r
purrr::map(dflist, ~.[stringr::str_starts(names(.), "A\\[")])
```

What this does is:

- For each sublist (`purrr::map`)

  - Select all elements of that sublist (`.[]`, where `.` is the sublist)
  - Whose names start with `A[` (`stringr::str_starts(names(.), "A\\[")`)

You got the top level `map` correct, since you want to modify the sublists. However, `map(keep, names(.) %in% "A[")` has some issues:

- `names(.) %in% "A["` should be a function or a formula (starting with `~`
- `purrr::keep` applies the filtering function to each *element* of the sublist, namely to the data frames directly. It never "sees" the names of each data frame. Actually I don't think you can use `keep` for this problem at all

Anyway this produces:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$`A[1]`
  W
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5

[[1]]$`A[2]`
   X
1  6
2  7
3  8
4  9
5 10


[[2]]
[[2]]$`A[1]`
   W
1 21
2 22
3 23
4 24
5 25

[[2]]$`A[2]`
   X
1 26
2 27
3 28
4 29
5 30


[[3]]
[[3]]$`A[1]`
   W
1 41
2 42
3 43
4 44
5 45

[[3]]$`A[2]`
   X
1 46
2 47
3 48
4 49
5 50
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to use `keep`, use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map(dflist, ~ keep(.x, str_detect(names(.x), fixed("A["))))
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't even know you could use `keep` in that way, since you're putting a vector and not a function as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here a **base R** solution:

```
lapply(dflist, function(x) x[grep("A\\[",names(x))] )

[[1]]
[[1]]$`A[1]`
  W
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5

[[1]]$`A[2]`
   X
1  6
2  7
3  8
4  9
5 10


[[2]]
[[2]]$`A[1]`
   W
1 21
2 22
3 23
4 24
5 25

[[2]]$`A[2]`
   X
1 26
2 27
3 28
4 29
5 30


[[3]]
[[3]]$`A[1]`
   W
1 41
2 42
3 43
4 44
5 45

[[3]]$`A[2]`
   X
1 46
2 47
3 48
4 49
5 50
```